# QGIS Plugin: NameError: global name 'QgsVectorLayer' is not defined

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am creating a plugin for QGIS where I, amongst other things, have to create a shapefile layer.

My problem is using the QgsVectorLayer. I tried following the answer in
 [Problem creating point shapefiles programmatically using python in QGIS 2.2](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87936/problem-creating-point-shapefiles-programmatically-using-python-in-qgis-2-2)

Which works great if I call it in the Python console in QGIS, but if I try to do it from my plugin, I get the error: "NameError: global name 'QgsVectorLayer' is not defined".

I am using QGIS 2.16.3

---

I already have 'from PyQt4.QtCore import *' shouldn't that be enough?

---

For some reason I thought qgis.core and PyQt4.QtCore were the same thing. It was the missing imports.

Comment: You need to import the classes you need to use in the header of the Python file, for instance: `from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer` If you need more classes from qgis.core, just append them, for instance: `from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsPoint`